# Python Dictionary Access Faster than List Index Access

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I performed several tests with dictionaries and lists to compare access speeds. Except for the case of 100 items in all other scenarios (with more items) dictionary access was faster than list index access. What is the reason behind this? The only reason I could think of was dictionaries initializing with large allocated memory and lists with limited memory and the copying time that is spent on lists when the number of items grow. Following is the code I used for the tests:

```
a = np.random.rand(1000000, 15)
large_list_of_lists = a.tolist()
keys = list('abcdefghijklmno')
large_list_of_dicts = [dict(zip(keys, values)) for values in large_list_of_lists]

def test_large_list_of_lists():
    list_total = 0
    for list_row in large_list_of_lists:
        for i in range(15):
            list_total += list_row[i]
    print(f'List total: {list_total}')
            
def test_large_list_of_dicts():
    dict_total = 0
    for dict_row in large_list_of_dicts:
        for k in keys:
            dict_total += dict_row[k]            
    print(f'Dict total: {dict_total}')


def timef(func):
    start_time = time.time()
    func()
    print(f'Time: {time.time()-start_time}')    

for f in [test_large_list_of_lists, test_large_list_of_dicts]:
    timef(f)

List total: 7498408.687142285
Time: 0.9701709747314453
Dict total: 7498408.687142285
Time: 0.6495280265808105
```

Comment: What times do you get when you replace the `+=` lines with `pass`? And better don't include `print`s in a benchmark. And where is `timef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the outset a very interesting test case evaluating two data structures in terms of performance for a use case. As I see you have neutralized the access edge that `Dictionary` has over `List` by making it index based access, which is now going to the memory index and fetching data and since Dictionary has keys stored as unique hash, for anything Dictionary test case has to be slower than List for that advantage, but its opposite.

> **1st Change:**

Replaced the mathematical operation with `continue` statement, idea is to completely remove the data access logic and understand if there's a difference, something like:

```
# Dictionary
for k in keys:
    continue

# List
for i in range(15):
    continue
```

But results are less than flattering, it leads to same issue more time for `Lists` and less for `Dictionary` even when the access operation is removed, which clarifies that issue lies somewhere else

> **2nd Change:**

Is `for i  in range(15)` same as `for k in keys`, doesn't seems to be the case, instead following two are same:

`for i in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]:` and `for k in keys` and this did the magic your are looking for, precisely the `List` operations becomes marginally faster with `continue` or the calcualtion that's been done.

> **Synopsis:**

In a operation  which access a set of number sequentially in huge data set something like `range(15)` is less efficient, probably it has an overload than simply reading the number and overall impact is few milliseconds delay when 15 million iterations, though not much of disadvantage but this seems to be the clear reason here, if you go in specific details.

Even now results aren't precisely same to milliseconds, which we know varies with variety of factors including hardware, cpu and is not within program's control at all points of time

Comment: I suppose your reasoning is correct; Lists ran faster when range was replaced with a list. Maybe this is because range is a generator.

Comment: I may not be aware of exact reason for this, but an informed guess would be a `generator` would yield a number, that would make it marginally slower in a such large iteration when compared to a pre-defined list. Certainly though `range` is a cleaner code practice